# Google drive choose account dialog not dismissed on back press

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In Google drive, can I choose account dialog box not dismissed when pressing back?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using `AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent()` from Google Play Services. In that case it is not much you can do as the dialog is a separate Activity that is implemented in Google Play Services.

Comment: No, i am not using this.
if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
     equinixApplication.setmGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
     mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(FileUploadListActivity.this)   
     .addApi(Drive.API)
     .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)                    
     .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
     .addConnectionCallbacks(FileUploadListActivity.this)
     .addOnConnectionFailedListener(FileUploadListActivity.this)
     .build();
    }else{
     mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

Comment: case  REQUEST_CODE_OPENER:
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    
    driveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);

    //Need to create File Drive object to get that file
    file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, driveId);
    file.getMetadata(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(metadataRetrievedCallback);
    file.open(mGoogleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).setResultCallback(contentsOpenedCallback);

   }else{
    finish();
   }
   break;

Comment: Can you update your original post with this code formatted so we can read it? This is impossible to understand.